# Azure Policy Guest Configuration - Find a VM with deactivated Windows Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I would like to write a Policy to find VMs with deactivated Windows Firewall.

At Azure Policy Templates i only have found a Policy with detailed Rules for the Windows Firewall.

Many thanks.

Best Regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer for Guest Policies. But have you considered using Azure DSC to enforce it? You can also monitor the compliance then within the automation account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-overview

E.g. using this module https://github.com/dsccommunity/NetworkingDsc/blob/main/source/Examples/Resources/FirewallProfile/1-FirewallProfile_ConfigurePrivateFirewallProfile_Config.ps1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer.

Mhh i must take a look on the Azur DSC.
Is it possible to use AZURE DSC with Azure ARC enabled Servers?

Comment: I have to pass on this one. Haven't used ARC before. I guess there might be a way, but can't tell for sure